# Node.js | Append Folders into 1 Folder but DONT append if toCopySIZE will make the FOLDER bigger 50MB

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to copy for example 4 files into 1 Folder

But lets say the 3 files are 22 MB each

so 44 MB = 2 files, and then the 3th file needs to be placed into another Folder

im currently looping tought a random folder array its not just 4 files this is an example to understand my situation

```
for await (const real_path of temp_paths) {

}
```

how can i archive this?

** Also what im not understanding::each Folder that we gona loop tought to Copy this Folder into the other Temp Folder is not allowed to be used against Copyie single files because that would corrupt the System of the actual Folder, we need to just copy the Folders over into new Folders with all Files inside, the 1 Folder will never extend the 50mb limit, but when been Combined it could.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
async function copyFilesToFolders(tempPaths, targetFolder, maxSize) {
  let currentSize = 0;
  let currentFolderIndex = 1;

  async function createNewFolder() {
    const newFolder = path.join(targetFolder, `Folder_${currentFolderIndex}`);
    await fs.mkdir(newFolder);
    currentFolderIndex++;
    currentSize = 0;
    return newFolder;
  }

  let currentFolder = await createNewFolder();

  for (const realPath of tempPaths) {
    const stats = await fs.stat(realPath);
    const fileSize = stats.size;

    if (currentSize + fileSize > maxSize) {
      // Create a new folder if adding the file would exceed the limit
      currentFolder = await createNewFolder();
    }

    // Copy the file to the current folder
    const fileName = path.basename(realPath);
    const destinationPath = path.join(currentFolder, fileName);
    await fs.copyFile(realPath, destinationPath);

    currentSize += fileSize;
  }
}

// Example usage
const tempPaths = ['/path/to/file1', '/path/to/file2', '/path/to/file3', '/path/to/file4'];
const targetFolder = '/path/to/targetFolder';
const maxSize = 50 * 1024 * 1024; // 50 MB

copyFilesToFolders(tempPaths, targetFolder, maxSize)
  .then(() => console.log('Files copied successfully'))
  .catch(err => console.error('Error copying files:', err));
```